# File path / Directory path not working

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, filepath

I get `500 (Internal Server Error)` when loading the file inside Codeigniter controller function. What I did is.

PHP:
public function load () {

```
$dir   = "_resources/documents";

  $files = scandir($dir);
  $ret   = array();
  foreach($files as $file) {
    if($file == "." || $file == "..")
    continue;
    $filePath = $dir."/".$file;

    $data = array(
      'name'  =>  $file,
      'path'  =>  $filePath,
      'size'  => filesize($filePath)
      );

    $ret[] = $data;
  }
    echo json_encode($ret);
 }
```

and when I inspect the element of the image it becomes

```
src = _resources/documents/example.jpg
```

Now in the console, the path becomes

```
http://localhost/project/document_items/_resources/documents/example.jpg
```

I wanted it to be

```
http://localhost/project/_resources/documents/example.jpg
```

Note that `document_items` is the name of my controller.

Jquery:

```
var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/project/";
var loadfile = baseurl + 'document_items/load';

$("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
onLoad:function(obj)
{
$.ajax({
cache: false,
url: loadfile,
dataType: "json",
success: function(data)
{
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
obj.createProgress(data[i]["name"],data[i]["path"],data[i]["size"]);
}
}
});
}
});
```

Comment: you can do this: `$dir = "../_resources/documents";`

Comment: @FrayneKonok, this also is not working. Maybe it's because of my jquery. I'll update my code above

Comment: You could try using FCPATH like `$dir  = FCPATH . "_resources/documents";`

Comment: @wolfgang1983, sorry but this outputs `C:\xampp\htdocs\project\_resources/documents/example.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

try using the following code snippet:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$dir = base_url("_resources/documents");
$files = scandir("_resources/documents");
```

Comment: I already did that actually but no luck. there's no images loaded.
but with `$dir = "_resources/documents"` the image loads but broken

Comment: and btw is `http://localhost/project/_resources/documents/example.jpg` accessible via the web browser??!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112569/discussion-between-mumen-yassin-and-claudios).